# Adding new records to Access database using c# using Copy If Newer

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've been working on a project recently and need to add new records of login information to an Access DB using windows forms. I have set the copy to output directory attribute to 'Copy if newer' however the data that is entered using the code below is never sent to the access file and is never saved to the DB. Is there something I need to add or does the problems lie elsewhere. Thanks.

```
        string name = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("What do you want to call this profile? (Must be between 3 and 12 charactrers)");
        string Username = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Input new Profile username. (Must be between 3 and 12 charactrers)");
        string Pin = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Input new Profile pin. (Must be 5 digits long)");
        p1.SetName(name);
        p1.SetUsername(Username);
        p1.SetPIN(Pin);
        SetID();
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=ProjectDatabases3.mdb";
        string SQL = "";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SQL = "INSERT INTO [LoginInfo] (ID,Name,Username,Pin) VALUES ('" + p1.GetID().ToString() + "','" + p1.GetName() + "','" + p1.GetUsername() +  "','" +  p1.GetPIN().ToString() + "');";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Added new record!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR- " + ex.ToString());
            listBox1.Items.Add("Failed!");
        }
```

Comment: If you do a SELECT for the same data immediately after the INSERT, does it come back with the data? What do you experience if you run the exe from the debug folder directly, instead of starting if from Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you try making the insert statment smaller, just to test. Lets say, try : "INSERT INTO [LoginInfo] (ID) VALUES (1);"  This rules out if it is an SQL Statment problem or a COnnection sting issue

Comment: @Crowcoder The SELECT query returns the original dummy data and not any new data that should be added through the program and running the exe from the debug folder does not have a difference on the INSERT query and the new entered data is still not copied to the database.

Comment: @MathiasZ By making the INSERT smaller I  did not have any issues with SQL Statement problem or Connection string issue.

Comment: Hy Alex, so this means that when you use the :  "INSERT INTO [LoginInfo] (ID) VALUES (1);" string instead of the one above that this works and you see an inserted value into your database ?